# dateformatting in gridview with date only

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, gridview

in my database `sql server`, there is a column name as date. in which I am inserting only date. but I retrieve the data from that table, then it show time with `date`. but I want only `date`. 
see here
 [image]

here is my code for `gridview`

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridIssue" runat="server" CssClass="grid" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="8" OnPageIndexChanging="GridIssue_PageIndexChanging">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <p style="margin-left: 10px;">No Book Has Been Issued Yet.</p>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>

    </asp:GridView>
```

how can I remove time from cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a bound field with the corresponding DateFormatString:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="DateFieldName" 
                HeaderText="MyDateTime"
                DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"  />
```

[MSDN on DateFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting htmlencode property to false and then use this:

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="action_issue_date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="action_yourdate" DataFormatString="{0:d}"  htmlencode="False">
```